# Printing number of command line arguments of Java application

Tags: java, command-line, arguments

suppose the arguments from the command line: Hello this is a message

I want to print to the screen the number of the arguments, for one time only and to be printed at the top.

also how to print, "message" before "this" or even before any arguments , however the user is going to write "this" at index 0, and "message" can be at any index?

```
 for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++)
{


if(i= args.length) {System.out.println(i);} //this command says, 
 you cannot convert from int to boolean

System.out.println(args.length); // this command prints repeatedly 



if (args[i].startsWith("this"){System.out.println(args[i]);}

if (args[i].startsWith("message"){System.out.println(args[i]);}

} // end of for
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(i = args.length) //Here is the problem
```

By mistake you are using single `'='` to compare i with args.length. You need to use `'=='` to compare i with args.length.

You need to do like below

```
if(i == args.length)
```

Comment: as mentioned in other answers, this is not the only problem, but certainly a big one

Comment: thank you  @Cruncher for your help, I'm trying to print the world message at the beginning, suppose the sender typed: (hello this is me and my message is...) or typed (hello this is message), message here can be at any index, how to print it first inside the for loop

Comment: @mijcara I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, you just want to print "message"? Or do you mean everything AFTER "message"? That may be a whole other question, but find the index of message, then do a for loop starting from message

Answer (score 1):

Your condition never `true`, It never goes inside.

See the reason.

```
 for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++)  //  looping with less  than.
{


if(i== args.length) {System.out.println(i);} //  condition ==.
```

How come it satisfies ? You got the point right ?

If you are unable to get adding @Cruncher's comment

*To explain this a little better: i < args.length and i == args.length are mutually exclusive conditions. That is, if one is true then the other is false. You need both to be true to get inside this if.*

Comment: To explain this a little better: `i < args.length` and `i == args.length` are mutually exclusive conditions. That is, if one is true then the other is false. You need both to be true to get inside this if.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is a number. `args.length` is also a number. Your mistake is that you are using only one `=` to check for equality instead of `==`. `=` is used to assign new values. So, `i` will get the value of `args.length` and your `if` cannot check if a number is true or false.

Also, you should use for-each instead of classic for.

```
for (String argument : args) {
  // do something with one argument
}
```

Even if you need the index, you will have less errors in your code if you use the for-each. For index, I am using another int/long variable that gets incremented inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(args.length);` prints repeatetly because it's in the for-loop.

If it should be printed only once and on top it has to be before the for-loop.

Furthermore because the loop runs from `i = 0`to `i < args.length` the expression `i == args.length` will never be true inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your logic is a little more complicated than it needs to be. You can print out the number of arguments by simply passing args.length to println. Then, if you want to print out certain arguments in an order of your choice, you can make a for loop for each, which will find if such an argument exists, and if so print it.

Example:

```
for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++)
{
if (args[i].startsWith("message"){System.out.println(args[i]);}
}

for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++)
{
if (args[i].startsWith("this"){System.out.println(args[i]);}
}
```

There are more elegant ways to print out arguments in the order you desire where they match certain terms, but this will work.